# Query rewriting encoding assertion checking to prevent sql injection attacks

Tags: mysql, encoding, sql-injection, assertion, rewriting

I was reading this paper: 
https://www.iitp.ac.in/~halder/Papers/Journal/ACSS_2016_2.pdf
and on page number 7 Database table (a) loginfo and sailinfo are describe.

Some queries are written

```
1. start;
2. Stmt = DriverManager.getConnection(” jdbc:mysql://172.16.1.16:1115/
demo”, ”scott”, ”tiger”).createStatement();
3. Resultset rs1 = Stmt.executeQuery(“SELECT eid FROM loginfo WHERE login = ' "+ slogin +" ' AND
pass = ’ ”+ spass +” ’ ” );
4. Resultset rs2 = Stmt.executeQuery(“SELECT ename FROM salinfo WHERE B sal> GP + ' "+vsal+" ' ”);
5. Resultset rs3 = Stmt.executeQuery(“SELECT ename FROM salinfo WHERE GP > ' "+ com +" ' *
’ ”+ rate +” ’ ”);
6. stop;
(b)
```

I want to build and convert the query from table (a) to queries as shown in table (b).

The way I wrote these queries for one example are as follows

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "thesis";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

echo "\n";

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

// sql input table queries
echo "Output";

//$sql="SELECT loginfo.eid FROM loginfo WHERE loginfo.login = (SELECT input.u_input_1 FROM input WHERE input.QID = 6 AND input.IID_1 = 1) AND loginfo.pass = (        //SELECT input.u_input_2 FROM input WHERE input.QID = 6 AND input.IID_2 = 2);";

$sql = "SELECT eid FROM loginfo WHERE login= (SELECT u_input_1 FROM input WHERE QID = 6 AND IID_1 = 1) AND pass = (SELECT u_input_2 FROM input WHERE QID = 6 AND IID_2 = 2) ;";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "\n \n eid: " . $row["eid"]."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

// sql input table queries
echo "Output";
$sql1 = "SELECT ename FROM salinfo WHERE GP > (SELECT u_input_1 FROM
INPUT WHERE QID = 10 AND IID_1 = 1);";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

$result = $conn->query($sql1);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "\n \n ename: " . $row["ename"]."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

// sql input table queries
echo "Output";
$sql2 = "SELECT ename FROM salinfo WHERE B_sal > GP + (SELECT u_input_1 FROM INPUT WHERE QID = 10 AND IID_1 = 1);";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

$result = $conn->query($sql2);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "\n \n ename: " . $row["ename"]."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

$conn->close();
?>
```

This technique which I have shown is called Query Re writing approach. I want to know if I want to implement it for generic queries this was just for one example then what could be a better way to do the same. Please help me with this approach.

Comment: Please don't do that. This makes no sense at all. Just use prepared statements and you're problems with regard to SQL injection are solved...

Comment: Ok sir..i repesct your statement.But can u help me out in this approach.I want to go for querry rewriting approach

Comment: Furthermore, 5.7 has a "query rewrite" facility builtin.  I blew the dust off this:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/queryrewrite

Comment: Is it possibIe for mysql 8.0?

Comment: ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library 'rewriter.dll' (errno: 2, The specified module could not be found.
)

Comment: source C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/share/install_rewriter.sql

Comment: can you help me out?i am facing this error.i have mysql server 8.0